# `save_model` requires h5py error occurss after installing h5py and cython packages too

Tags: tensorflow, anaconda, keras-layer

I need to save my  new sequential model but when I use the model.save(filename),it shows error like save_model requires hp5y.I tried installing h5py in conda by  'conda install -c anaconda h5py'command. And I also installed cython,but then the error exists .what should I do?

Comment: I run this in pycharm tool where the environment is conda environment.Is there any solution for this?

Comment: Please share how you fixed this by posting it as an answer to your own question

Comment: I just included the package of h5py in pycharm tool

Answer (score 0):

one should include the package in pycharm project interpreter after being downloaded in the conda environment.